# How can we use inner variable from function calling in node js at outside?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, mongoose

```
var limit = 0;

Settings.find({ settings: "settings" }, function (err, docs) {
    limit=docs[0].keywords;  //6
    console.log('Limit from Inner : ' + limit);
});

console.log('Limit from Out : ' + limit);
```

It will give me output like :
"Limit from Out : 0
Limit from Inner : 6"

I want call inner first and out put like :
"Limit from Out : 6
Limit from Inner : 6"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js is async, `console.log('Limit from Out : ' + limit);` is executed before the callback of `Settings.find()` is invoked.

if you must do what you described, you can use some control flow library such as https://github.com/caolan/async and do something like:

```
var limit = 0;

async.series([
    function(callback) {
        Settings.find({ settings: "settings" }, function (err, docs) {
            limit=docs[0].keywords;  //6
            console.log('Limit from Inner : ' + limit);
            callback(err);
        });
    }
], function(err) {
    console.log('Limit from Out : ' + limit);
});
```